# Messages cipher and solutions

Tags: hundreds

There are several "messages" (codes with scrambled messages) awarded as achievements in *Hundreds*. Is there an in-game hint to their cipher? What is the cipher? What are their solutions/translations? Are they used for anything in the game?

Please use the spoilers markup: `>!`

[image: EERNSITCEPS]
[image: XK BOOLO]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first riddle (3) says: "A Mouse Has One Snout But A Hand Has Five"

Solution:

> Place five fingers onto the iPad screen

The second riddle (11) in an anagram, move letters around until you get the right words.

Solution:

> Persistence Without Patience Is A Golden Harp Missing Its Chord

The third riddle (24) is a replacement cipher. You just need to figure out by how many letters to shift.

Solution:

> An Error At The Function Cipherscreen Line Ten Expected Semicolon

The fourth riddle (31) is a transposition cipher.You must arrange the letters in a set number of columns to reveal the answer.

Solution:

> Hahaha Or Laughing Or Laughter Or Success Or Hello World

I have the fifth riddle (45) but I have yet to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

First:

> Each word as an anagram "Persistence without patience is a golden harp missing its chord"

Second:

> Caesar cipher with a shift of 3 "An error at the function cipherscreen line ten expected semicolon"

Comment: you've actually posted the second and third solution, not the 1st and second.

Comment: To be fair I was posting the solution to the 2 messages in the original question, but yes you are correct

Comment: ah, I see. apologies.